# Aggregate results based on case statement

Tags: sql

Need some assistance writing a query. Suppose I'm using a table `sales` shown here:

```
trans_id    item_number     sales 
   1            1             10
   1            11            5
   2            11            3
   2            13            4
```

I want my output to contain `trans_id`, total sales for the transaction and a Y/N flag
that can be determined by this case statement: `CASE WHEN item_number BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN  'Y' ELSE 'N' END`.

However, I need the flag to be applied at the aggregate level where if there is at least 1 item with a 'Y' flag, then the whole transaction should include a `'Y'` flag. If no items have a `'Y'` flag, then the entire transaction should be flagged `'N'`. The output should essentially look like:

```
trans_id    flag        sales
   1         'Y'          15
   2         'N'          7
```

The query below nearly gets me there, but I would have to use it as a subquery
to get me the expected results. Is it possible to modify the `CASE` statement or use
some other approach so that I can get the desired results within the same `SELECT`
statement (i.e. not using the query below as a subquery)?

```
SELECT trans_id
  , CASE WHEN item_number BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
  , SUM(sales)
FROM sales
GROUP BY trans_id, item_number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max()`:

```
select trans_id,
       max(case when item_number between 1 and 10 then 'Y' else 'N' end),
       sum(sales)
from sales
group by trans_id;
```

With `'Y'` and `'N'`, `MAX()` acts as an aggregate-OR operation.  `MIN()` would be an aggregate-AND -- that is,all the item numbers are in that range.

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't aware the `MAX()` function worked this way